# Difference in httpclient implementation between Flutter and Angular?

Tags: angular, api, flutter, asynchronous, promise

Currently developing a site with the Angular framework I found myself facing a situation that confuses me and makes me wonder.

Indeed, like the majority of websites / applications in 2020, the user has the possibility to identify himself to his account in order to access his personal information.

Having already developed a Flutter application to train myself, I had set up an identification system via login/password using calls to an API.

This call is visible in the image below. As you can see in this picture, I retrieve the API response thanks to an await on the POST request.

Then I made a switch on the statusCode of my answer.

[image: Flutter api call]

And this is where my question comes.
I thought I'd take the same thought for my Angular site, but a "problem" arises.

When I set up this "method" under Angular, if I enter bad user information, I don't really get an answer, but the browser tells me that there was an error.

You will see the different scenarios in the two captures below.

[image]

My question is finally "simple":

**Why can I switch on Flutter response's statuCode & not in Angular ?
more precisely, why are the 400 answers considered as errors in Angular and not in Flutter?**

**Simply a difference in implementation between the 2 frameworks?**

Answer (score 1):

It's a difference in the frameworks. However you can still do what you are after with Angular using the observable's pipe and the catchError operator. (This assumes you are using a recent version of Angular)

```
this.http.post(..).pipe(
    catchError((err) => {
        switch(err.status) {
            case 400: {
               // Do something
               break;
            }
            case 500: {
               // Do something
               break;
            }
            default: { 
               //Do something 
               break; 
            } 
        }
    }).toPromise();
```

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer & for the trick with the pipe :)